# Which applications and programs are vital at Startup?

Tags: startup

The following applications from below are in my list of Startup. Which one of them are strict necessary for the system? How can I remove those not necessary from Startup (but not from my laptop)?

1. AT-SPI D-BUS BUS
2. Backup Monitor
3. Bluetooth Manager
4. Certificate and Key Storage
   Gnome Keyring: PKCS#11 Component
5. Chat
   Telepathy indicator service
6. Check for new hardware drivers
   Notify about new hardware drivers ...
7. Desktop Sharing
   Gnome Desktop sharing server
8. Disk Notifications
   Provides notifications related to disks
9. Files
10. Gnome Settings Daemon
11. GPG Password Agent
    Gnome Keyring: GPG Agent
12. GSettings Data Conversion
    Migrates user settings from Gconf to dconf
13. Gwibber
    Update your microblog and view others' statuses
14. Mount Helper
15. Network
16. Onboard
17. Orca screen reader
18. Personal File Sharing
19. PolicyKit Authentication Agent
20. PulseAudio Sound system
21. Screensaver
22. Secret Storage Service
23. SSH Key Agent
24. Ubuntu One
25. Update Notifier
26. User folders update
27. Zeitgeist DdataHub

Thanks, 
J.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which startup applications can I safely disable?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/310337/which-startup-applications-can-i-safely-disable)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could safely disable all of them except for 1,4,9,11,12,15,19,20,23, and there shouldn't be any problem. It depends, however, of the programs you usually use and what they depend on.

Comment: You don't need 15. Network starts the nm-applet. You can always enable it later. Just run nm-applet from a commandline.