# Disable unnecessary startup services and applications

Tags: 12.04, performance

What is the best practices to disable unnecessary startup services and applications? This post is very useful when i came to decide what to disable [Which startup applications can I safely disable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310337/which-startup-applications-can-i-safely-disable/310742#310742) , but i cannot find how to start! also i cannot find anything related to services.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the dock and search for Startup Applications. The GUI is very simple and you can remove programs from the list to stop them from automatically starting. Only remove programs that you know are not essential.

Answer (score 0):

According to [**UpstartCookBook**](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/):

> ```
> With Upstart 0.6.7, to stop Upstart automatically starting a job, 
> you can either:
>
>     - Rename the job configuration file such that it does not end with 
>       ".conf".
>     - Edit the job configuration file and comment out the "start on" stanza 
>       using a leading '#'.
>
> To re-enable the job, just undo the change.
> ```

Another better approach is:

> ```
> With Upstart 1.3, you can make use of an "override file" and the manual 
> stanza to achieve the same result in a simpler manner:
>
> # echo "manual" >> /etc/init/myjob.override
>
> Note that you could achieve the same effect by doing this:
>
> # echo "manual" >> /etc/init/myjob.conf
>
> However, using the override facility means you can leave the original job 
> configuration file untouched.
>
> To revert to the original behaviour, either delete or rename the override 
> file (or remove the manual stanza from your ".conf" file).
> ```

[**manual**](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#manual) stanza tell Upstart to ignore the `start on`/`stop on` stanzas.

In order to disable **SystemV** init service:

> ```
> To enable/disable a service in a particular runlevel, you only need to
> create/remove a symbolic link in a particular directory or set of 
> directories.
> ```

This means that you should remove symbolic link in `/etc/rc**runlevel**.d/NN**name**`  whose  target is script `/etc/init.d/name`

Another better approach is [**update-rc.d**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) command that can disable service:

```
   update-rc.d name disable
```

You can stop service and start service manually until `/etc/init.d/name` exists.

To disable service permanently, remove `/etc/init.d/name`.

**Be careful what you do**, disable service or job can result an unusable system.

Finally, this is a useful link on [**how to disable Gnome Session Startup applications**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1067101) and here another on [**How do I make a program auto-start every time I log in?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30931/how-do-i-make-a-program-auto-start-every-time-i-log-in) where you can learn where information are stored and which GUI are available, so I guess you should find out how to disable session application on your system.