# A black screen on boot and nothing happens afterwards

Tags: boot, apache2

When I start my laptop, it shows a black screen with these messages and nothing happens afterwards.

```
 • PulseAudio configured for per-user sessions
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,   
using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

[  16.603178] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
[  16.603305] ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: wl_ops_info_changed: associated
[  16.603420] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 0 (implement)
[  16.953463] ieee80211 phy0: wl_ops_info_changed: arp filtering: enabled true, count 1 (implement)
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n

Comment: what did you change on your system? why is it not starting anymore?

Comment: I changed nothing, I switched on my laptop after 25 days and saw this error window. 25 days before, it was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Once the system is hang, try pressing few common combinations such as:

- <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
- <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

If this won't help, run the system in a [single mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/132965/78223) and investigate your logs and startup scripts.

The [Apache2 warning](https://askubuntu.com/q/256013/78223) isn't the main cause of the issue, so you should check further more.

You may want to boot your Ubuntu with more verbose output and see if anything can come up.

Check also available Actions using [magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) which can help you to dump kernel debug info or kill the hang processes.

Consider also disabling startup services, see: [Which startup applications can I safely disable?](https://askubuntu.com/q/310337/78223)